# Rendering new stratigraphic classification using QGIS Midvatten plugin on plot

Tags: qgis, midvatten

I've a borehole with a new stratigraphy classification: `lignite`.
First I've inserted (add) the new `strata` item into the `zz_statigraphy_plot` table and into the `zz_strat` table.

```
zz_strat table: 

geoshort | strata
-----------------
Lignite  | lignite


zz_stratigraphy_plots table:

strata  | color_mplot | hatch_mplot | color_qt  | brush_qt
------------------------------------------------------------
lignite | DarkGreen   | -           | darkGreen | HorPattern


obsid   stratid depthtop    depthbot    geology geoshort    capacity    development comment
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST01  1       0           8           peat    peat        0       
TEST01  2       8           12          clay    clay        2   
TEST01  3       12          16          lignite lignite     1
```

Then I have inserted (add) the stratigraphy information into the stratigraphy table. I am able to view the stratigraphy plot but the fill color in the logplot is just white in the new stratigraphy item.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this a typo or do you have lower and uppercase mixed for your new stratigraphy classification: lignite?